# Download files from other server php

Tags: php, file, download

I have a problem with copying files to local server. I've got only the last file, plashka_3.png.

> Warning: copy(http://rus-yurist.ru/images/plashka_1.png )
>   [function.copy]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>
> Warning: copy(http://rus-yurist.ru/images/plashka_2.png )
>   [function.copy]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

```
$txt="http://rus-yurist.ru/images/plashka_1.png
      http://rus-yurist.ru/images/plashka_2.png
      http://rus-yurist.ru/images/plashka_3.png";

$a1=explode("\n",$txt);
$a1=array_unique($a1);

foreach($a1 as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url); 
    $path_parts = pathinfo($url); 
    $path = 'docs/'.$path_parts['basename'];
    copy($url, $path);
 //  file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url)); /* not works too, only last file
}
```

Comment: Why not just store the images in an array in the first place?

Comment: If you really must do it like this, you should trim your `$url` variable.

Comment: Thanks, that was a problem!

Comment: What's the cURL for? It doesn't look like you actually use it, from the code you posted. Am I missing something?

Comment: it's left from code when i use curl, forgot delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use file_put_contents

```
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I should  trim my $url variable! Thanks to jeroen!